# Is Cyanogen fully compatible with Play services and stock android apps?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, compatibility

I am considering the upgrade of my Android Phone to Cyanogenmod as even with root, I am having several permissions problems, OTA updates removing root, etc.

The only reason I did not yet install it is because I don't know if it is compatible with the Play Store, and apps related. As I have alot of apps downloaded through the play store, and an AppData helium backup, I want to know if the backup will be compatible with the apps in Cyanogen.

My helium backup only has the backup of App Data, rather than the entire application source, as it is more space efficient

---

Samsung Galaxy S5 mini SM-G800F with stock Android 4.4.2 rooted

Comment: I am not sure for the backup (especially for system apps), but as long as you remember to flash GApps (Google Apps), you are good to go and all Google Play services will work like normal.

Comment: You can actually test this on your own. All you've to do is to make a [tag:nandroid] backup of your current stock ROM using a custom recovery, then wipe the ROM, flash your desired CM version, flash compatible GApps, restore those app backups, restart and see what happens. If it doesn't work, use the nandroid backup to fall back to stock ROM.

Comment: @GiantTree I forgot to mention that the App backup is only for the app data, not for the actual application

Comment: @TheBro21 for non-system apps I'm sure it works but system apps like SMS or settings may not work.

Comment: @GiantTree I think I will go with testing it by dualboot, or with crossed fingers. You can put instructions on dualboot or nandroid backup in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, Cyanogenmod is in fact compatible with play services. I am not sure about the stock apps that samsung has, as I didn't even bother trying to install them. The `adb` backup I made before going to CM restored properly. Google Apps are copyrighted, that's why they are not there initially. You can flash the Open GApps package as I found that to work for me best.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Cyanogenmod is fully compatible with your previous apps.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the informations. But I would like some more detail. And also, will Helium backup of apps work?